# problem with passing argument to QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start()

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

So i have this member function in AntiFlood class:

```
void AntiFlood::unBan()
{
    QThread::msleep(5000);
    std::string lineToPost = "KICK " + roomToPost +" "+ nickToPost + "\r\n";
    sendIT(lineToPost);
}
```

and i want to pass it to:
threadpool.globalInstance()->start(unBan);

- which doesnt work - results with error: no matching function for call to 'QThreadPool::start()'  threadpool.globalInstance()->start(unBan);
  ^;
  but on the other hand if i use lambda:

  ```
    auto lam = [this, room, nick](){
        QThread::msleep(5000);
        std::string lineToPost = "KICK " + roomToPost +" "+ nickToPost + "\r\n";
        sendIT(lineToPost);
    };
    threadpool.globalInstance()->start(lam);
  ```

it works fine.
How do i pass void AntiFlood::unBan( ) to  threadpool.globalInstance()->start(), which demands std::function<void()> functionToRun ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem you're seeing is that `AntiFlood::unBan` is (or at least 'appears to be') a non-static member function.  That being the case it must be invoked against a valid object of type `AntiFlood`.  Since [`QThreadPool::start`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html#start-1) has the signature...

```
void QThreadPool::start(std::function<void ()> functionToRun, int priority = 0)
```

you need to pass it a 'self contained' `std::function<void()>` which is precisely what you're done with...

```
auto lam = [this, room, nick]()
  {
    QThread::msleep(5000);
    std::string lineToPost = "KICK " + roomToPost +" "+ nickToPost + "\r\n";
    sendIT(lineToPost);
  };
threadpool.globalInstance()->start(lam);
```

by capturing `this` in the lambda.

In short, I'd say the way you're doing things currently *is* the correct/accepted way.